# Can't implement simple custom icon google maps example in JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, google-maps-api-3, jetty

When I try to implement the following simple example in jsp on Jetty Server: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-simple I get a java.io.UTFDataFormatException and no icon is displayed on the map
The piece of code that produces the error is:

```js
var image = 'images/beachflag.png';
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.890542, 151.274856);
var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    icon: image
});
```

if I comment out the icon variable of the marker like below, then everything works fine.

```js
var image = 'images/beachflag.png';
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.890542, 151.274856);
var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map
<!--  icon: image -->
});
```

Although of course the standard google marker is displayed then and not the custom icon which I want.

This is my stacktrace using jetty-maven-plugin 9.2.10.v20150310:

```
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
2015-04-23 19:32:35.640:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:qtp1142653826-19: 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:579)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:405)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet.service(JettyJspServlet.java:107)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: 
java.io.UTFDataFormatException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
    at org.apache.jasper.xmlparser.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(UTF8Reader.java:621)
    at org.apache.jasper.xmlparser.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:486)
    at org.apache.jasper.xmlparser.XMLEncodingDetector.load(XMLEncodingDetector.java:961)
    at org.apache.jasper.xmlparser.XMLEncodingDetector.skipString(XMLEncodingDetector.java:916)
    at org.apache.jasper.xmlparser.XMLEncodingDetector.scanXMLDecl(XMLEncodingDetector.java:1164)
    at org.apache.jasper.xmlparser.XMLEncodingDetector.getEncoding(XMLEncodingDetector.java:116)
    at org.apache.jasper.xmlparser.XMLEncodingDetector.getEncoding(XMLEncodingDetector.java:104)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.determineSyntaxAndEncoding(ParserController.java:304)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:183)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parseDirectives(ParserController.java:117)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:194)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:564)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:405)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet.service(JettyJspServlet.java:107)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Edit: Changed stacktrace produced by latest jetty-server  9.2.10.v20150310

Comment: [Jetty-8 is EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html)

Comment: Thanks. I changed it to latest stable release, still the same problem. Although the stacktrace have changed a little bit I have updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must either modify the path to the image or upload the icon to your own server.

When you don't see the marker the image may not be found.

They use a relative URL `'images/beachflag.png'` which will in the example point to:

```
https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png
```

[image]

---

```js
      function initialize() {
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.890542, 151.274856);

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
          center: myLatLng,
          zoom: 10
        });
        var image = 'https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png';

        var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          icon: image
        });
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
      html {
        height: 100%
      }
      body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0
      }
      #map-canvas {
        height: 100%
      }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3">
</script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I already made sure though that the image can be found, it's on my server. When I change the filename for example so the image can't be found, there is no long exception.
 But I get the following short error:
 `[INFO] Started Jetty Server Apr 23, 2015 8:31:04 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet serviceJspFile SEVERE: PWC6117: File "C%3A%5CUsers%5CFerdinand%5Cprojects%5Cspring-hibernate-20120924%5Csrc%5Cmain%5Cwebapp%5Cview%5Cmap%5Cimages%5CbeachflagXx.png" not found`